# Error launching application on iPhone. After upgrade Xcode 15 ios 17 flutter 3.16

Tags: flutter, xcode

I upgrade my iphone to 17.2.1 Xcode 15.2 and flutter 3.16.7 after this I can't run a flutter example on android studio (I have a white screen) but when I run from Xcode it's OK
Android studio automation is well actived

```
Xcode build done.                                           14,4s
You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation.
Installing and launching...                                         4,6s
Error launching application on iPhone.


flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.7, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Comment: check the first solution from this link. It works for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78156098/23791088