# impossible to run on physical ios device after xcode 15 upgrade

Tags: flutter, xcode

after upgrade xcode to v15 and flutter to 3.16.7
Now I can't run my flutter app on my physical ios device from android studio but I can run on simulator. And I can run on physical ios device if I run from Xcode but not android studio.

When I run on android studio and on a physical device I have 2 pop up

```
-Cannot open 'idevicesyslog' because the developer cannot be verified.


-An instance of “Runner” is already running. Would you like to terminate it and launch a new instance?
```

I have this terminal message

```
 -You may be prompted to give access to control Xcode. Flutter uses Xcode to run your app. If access is not allowed, you can change this through your Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation.
```

I have verify Settings > Privacy & Security > Automation android studio is well activated, but I have no icon of Xcode

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

When the popup indicates

> “iproxy” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

`Move to trash` | `Cancel`

Select `Cancel`, then go to `Apple > Sistem settings > Privacy and Security`, the "iproxy" will request permission, select to `Allow anyway`

Repeat the process if ***"idevicesyslog"*** or ***"idevice_id"*** is requesting the same.

**Rerun, now your App should launch in physical device normally.**

*In my case the error was occurring due to the port to run VM service in Xcode was different from the one used in VS Code, this seems to be handled by iproxy*

Answer (score 0):

after upgrading flutter, flutter apps are not running on IOS 17 or higher i have checked it on many device. its there is nothing wrong with your device or Xcode. its because of flutter upgradation